# Kotlin getter / setter when using a primary constructor

Tags: kotlin

The example is from a Kotlin-course I'm doing:

```
class Car {
    var speed: Int = 0
        get() = field 
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
}
```

If I like to use a primary constructor like this:

```
class Car(var speed: Int)
```

**How would I have to write the getter / setter in that case?**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You cannot write getters/setters inside of the constructor, you can do the following:

1. Create variable inside class whose value taken from constructor.

```kotlin
class Car(speed: Int) {
    var speed = speed
        get() = field 
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
}
```

2. Use `@JvmField` annotation to restrict compiler not to auto-generate getters/setters and implement one yourself

```kotlin
class Car(@JvmField private var speed: Int) {
    fun getSpeed() = speed
    fun setSpeed(value: Int) { speed = value }
}
```

Comment: You need a private backing field, otherwise the compiler complains that: "Initializer is not allowed here because this property has no backing field"

Comment: Im new at this JVM/Kotlin interop, but seems like "JvmField has no effect on a private property" as far I understand the second example should remove "private"

Comment: To anybody still confused by method #1 above:  the key here is you must remove val/var.  So `class Car(speed: Int)` NOT `class Car(var speed : Int)`, which creates a duplicate + conflicting declaration.

Answer (score 8):

You can just initialize your property with the value from constructor:

```kotlin
class Car(speed: Int) {
    var speed: Int = speed
        get() = field
        set(value) {
            field = value
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax of property –**

```
var <propertyName>[: <PropertyType>] [= <property_initializer>]
    [<getter>]
    [<setter>]
```

Here, property initializer, getter and setter are optional. We can also omit property type if it can be inferred from the initializer.
The syntax of a read-only or immutable property declaration differs from a mutable one in two ways:
starts with val instead of var, and does not allow a setter.

In kotlin, `val` is used as only for read means getter and `var` is used as for not `getter()` and `setter()`

```
class Company {
var name: String = "Defaultvalue"
}
```

The above code is equivalent to the below code

```
class Company {
    var name: String = "defaultvalue"
        get() = field                     // getter
        set(value) { field = value }      // setter
}
```

You can also use kotlin `data class` if you want to hold data in your `Car` class. so you no need to define getter and setter.

```
data class Car(var speed: Int)
```

For more check https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Comment: "so you no need to define getter and setter." You don't need to define them for non-`data` class either.

Comment: Yes, in kotlin you no need to define getter setter manually. Getter and setter is optional in kotlin